# C# Tic Tac Toe Minimax algorithm

Tags: c#, algorithm, artificial-intelligence, tic-tac-toe, minimax

I am making a Tic Tac Toe game in WPF C# using Minimax algorithm. I think my algorithm is working fine, but I am having trouble understanding what should I do to get the next state of board from calling function Minimax. For now it only returns the final state. The code for Algorithm is following:

```
    Move MiniMax(char[,] state, bool playerMAX, int depth)
    {
        if (depth == 0 || CountEmptyFields(state).Count() == 0 || CheckIfStateIsList(state))  //check if state is terminal or we reached depth
        {
            Move ret = new Move();
            ret.SetState(state);
            ret.SetHV(HeuristicValue(state));  //method that calculates heuristic value
            return ret;
        }

        Move choice = new Move();  //class that has two variables: state and value

        int val = 0;


        if (playerMAX)
        {
           val = -10000;
        }
        else
        {
            val = 10000;
        }
        List<char[,]> M = new List<char[,]>();
        M = GeneratePossibleMoves(state, playerMAX);  //function that generates all possible moves
        foreach(char[,] child in M)
        {
            Move candidate = new Move();
            candidate = MiniMax(child, SwitchPlayer(playerMAX), depth - 1);
            if (playerMAX && candidate.GetHV()>val)
            {
                val = candidate.GetHV();
                choice.SetHV(candidate.GetHV());
                choice.SetState(candidate.GetState());
            }
            else if(!playerMAX && candidate.GetHV() < val)
            {
                val = candidate.GetHV();
                choice.SetHV(candidate.GetHV());
                choice.SetState(candidate.GetState());
            }
        }
        return choice;
    }
```

As I said the algorithm returns the final state of game... how can I get only the next move? Please help.

Comment: It's hard to say without the context of the rest of your programs design. Generally speaking though, it's going to recurse all the way down the call stack and then return all the way up so you're going to get the final result. If you want to preserve all the 'decisions' it makes along the way' you could add a container reference arg to the recursive funtion and add each choice to that as you decend down the call stack

Comment: should I post any additional code (methods that I use in MiniMax) so it would be easier for you to help me with my question? I am really frustrated about how to get only the next move and not only the final result...

Comment: I think it would best if you draw the various steps of the call stack on a small example. Your MiniMax seems to be doing what a MiniMax is meant to do. I think you're just misunderstanding how it's functioning recursively

Comment: Do you think it would be ok, if I for example got all the possible moves from a current move and call the Minimax algorithm for each of those moves and sort possible moves I got earlier at the beginning according to Minimax values and get the best next move this way?